# Error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes, node-crypto

I am trying to decrypt a PDF file using node js,PDF file encrypted by third party using C#

I am having a hard time because I keep getting this error:

```
    Error: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length
        at Decipheriv._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:141:29)
        at Decipheriv.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:142:10)
        at Decipheriv.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at Decipheriv.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
        at prefinish (_stream_writable.js:676:14)
        at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:684:5)
        at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:704:3)
        at Decipheriv.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:633:5)
        at decryptAES (D:\IMP\AESENCRYPTION\index.js:91:11)
        at D:\IMP\AESENCRYPTION\index.js:189:22
    Emitted 'error' event on Decipheriv instance at:
        at done (_stream_transform.js:209:19)
        at _stream_transform.js:143:7
        at Decipheriv._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:143:5)
        at Decipheriv.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:142:10)
        [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
        at Decipheriv.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:633:5) {
      library: 'digital envelope routines',
      function: 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex',
      reason: 'data not multiple of block length',
      code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_DATA_NOT_MULTIPLE_OF_BLOCK_LENGTH'
    }
```

**we are using below code for encryption(C#)**

```
public async Task<byte[]> Encrypt(byte[] textToEncrypt, string masterKeyId)
        {
            var kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient("AKIATQHPMFI7PCSZ2EPR", "9PKzz5BdJgpcs1dGiamwzsyhl3rQfWzxwkJGMpfF", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            using (var algorithm = Aes.Create())
            {
                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Generates the data key under the master key
                    var dataKey = await kmsClient.GenerateDataKeyAsync(new GenerateDataKeyRequest
                    {
                        KeyId = masterKeyId,
                        KeySpec = DataKeySpec.AES_256
                    });

                    msEncrypt.WriteByte((byte)dataKey.CiphertextBlob.Length);
                    dataKey.CiphertextBlob.CopyTo(msEncrypt);
                    algorithm.Key = dataKey.Plaintext.ToArray();

                    // Writing algorithm.IV in output stream for decryption purpose.
                    msEncrypt.Write(algorithm.IV, 0, algorithm.IV.Length);

                    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);

                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(textToEncrypt))
                        {
                            input.CopyTo(csEncrypt);
                            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }
                        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**we are using below code for decryption(Node js)**

```
const algorithm = 'AES-256-CBC';

    const iv = Buffer.from('00000000000000000000000000000000');
 
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm,key,iv);
  decipher.setAutoPadding(false)
// we are checking different ways but facing same issue.
//type 1
 decipher.write(buffer);
 decipher.end();
 return decipher.read();

//type 2

return Buffer.concat([
       decipher.update(buffer), 
        decipher.final()
      ]).toString()

//type 3
var decrypted = decipher.update(buffer,'utf8','biary') + decipher.final('binary');
//type 4
decoded = decipher.update(buffer);
decipher += decipher.final();
```

Unable to decrypt a pdf file Using 'aes-256-cbc' algorithm in node js

Comment: Where do the key and IV come from in the NodeJS code? The C# code uses the _AWS Key Management Service_ and stores the length of the encrypted key, the encrypted key and the IV together with the ciphertext in the returned `byte[]`. Presumably in the NodeJS code this data must be separated beforehand and the key decrypted (for the latter see e.g. [here, section _Decrypting a data key_](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-encryption.html)) before decrypting the ciphertext.

Comment: key come from AWS Key Management Service. IV use static like in  code

Comment: For the decryption you need the decrypted key. If you have this, great, otherwise I have described above how you can determine the encrypted key from the stored data and decrypt it. On the other hand you need the IV, which also has to be retrieved from the stored data (a static IV will probably not work with respect to the C# code).

Comment: I had decrypted key .i  retrieved IV from the stored data and C# developer team provided IV.In both ways getting same error(data not multiple of block length)

Comment: The C# code returns a `byte[]` containing the following data: _**en**crypted key length || **en**crypted key || IV || **actual** ciphertext_. If you have the **de**crypted key and the IV, you still need the **actual** ciphertext. With this decryption should be possible! You can find examples for this in the [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_decipher), which essentially match the code snippet you posted. If the returned `byte[]` has been encoded, an appropriate decoding may be needed (e.g. Base64). Without sample data, unfortunately I can't say more.